# PHP Read File into Array

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload, csv

I need to extract data from a CSV file and insert it into a MySQL database.

(see sample file below)

So far I have an array with the entire file (reading file with PHP):

`Array ([0] => 01 [1] => 12345678X [2] => Title [3] => 120.00` ...etc.

How can I modify the array to create groups of four for each item? Each item is its own array?

For example:

```
array( array (01,ISBN,Name,Price),
       array (01,ISBN,Name,Price)
      );
```

Additionally, how can I access those values individually and insert into MySQL?

Ex:
`$price = 1.25;` <--in array

This is what I have so far:

```
    $fp = @fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    if ($fp) {

         $arr = array();
         while(!feof($fp)) {
          $this_line = fgets($fp);  

          $line = explode("^",$this_line);

          if($line[0] != "") {          
              array_push($arr,$line[0]);
              }
          $i++;
         }
```

The above code returns one big array with each column an an element. I would like arrays of four elements per array within one large array so that I can access each "row" individually.

Sample file:

```
ID 01
Title This is the title
Price 120.00
ISBN xxxxxx
^
ID 02
Title This is the title
Price 20.00
ISBN xxxxxx
^
```

Comment: How are the fields separated (per line) within your file?

Comment: Unfortunately by spaces...so it cannot be easily parsed since the title has spaces in it.

Comment: @Mr, Jones: One space or multiple spaces?

Comment: For the specific file I am working with, no, unfortunately spaces :(

Comment: One space, however the title of the book has spaces in between the title.

Comment: @Mr.Jones In that case, you really should quote the book title field, eg `01 12345678X "Name of Book" 120.00` otherwise, it's going to need an ugly `preg_match()` solution

Comment: I just updated my question with the code that I have so far. It gives me each line broken up by column, however it is one big array. How can I create arrays of each line (4 items per array)?

Comment: @Mr.Jones, but why won't you just work with `$line` instead of pushing it into the big array?

Comment: $line does not allow me to access each column individually. For example, I would like to have an array of four elements:             $isbn = ""; $id = "";  $title = ""; $price = "";  I need to be able to access each of the four elements in an array of four values.

Comment: @Mr.Jones Are you able to change the file format at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The delimiter for each "block" of four elements is: "^". I need to group the elements into arrays of four and access each element individually.

Comment: I added some sample data so you can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 3):

Use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), avoid CSV parsing issues.

It will return the file line-by-line, in arrays, which is what you are asking for.

Then you can use MySQLi's [prepared statement with bound parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to insert the lines.

**[EDIT]** something like this:

```
$file = fopen('data.csv', 'r');
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT blah blah blah VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
  $stmt->bind_param('types string', $row[0], $row[1], etcetera);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: ... or PDO, much easier prepare / binding API

Comment: This also means you can process one line at a time, instead of trying to slurp the whole file into memory.

Comment: @Phil: Can you leave some quick pointers about the PDO stuff and csv?

Comment: I just updated my question with the code that I have so far. It gives me each line broken up by column, however it is one big array. How can I create arrays of each line (4 items per array)

Comment: @hakre [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). IMO, a much clearer API for preparing statements and binding parameters than the `mysqli` offering

Comment: I added a sample file to my question. This solution will not work for the file I am trying to parse.